# Wrong entries in webpages_Roles table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a standard ASP.NET MVC project in VS12 using the "Internet Application" Template for Web Applications.

VS has automatically created a database called `aspnet-Authentification-20130123105949.mdf`. When I open the database table `webpages_Roles` just one of my created Roles is shown there. But this role doesn't exist anymore, it seems as if the data shown here is old.

I add roles by using:

```
public String AddRole(String name)
        {
            Roles.CreateRole(name);
            return name + " was added.";
        }
```

My method to list the roles shows different roles than in the DB view:

```
public String ListRoles()
{
    String[] roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
    String res = "";
    foreach(String role in roles) {
        res += "\n" + role;
    }
    return res;
}
```

I've already tried to refresh the DB View, but this does not help.
I have no problems with other databases created by myself.

Comment: Your role is shown in the table, but it doesn't exist anymore? Where? Do you have Migrations or a DatabaseInitializer set up?